# just select one checkbox in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkboxlist

How can I create the method when I click on one checkbox other checkbox unselceted and just can select one of them.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Tablerow extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    let {listwebsites} = this.props;
    listwebsites.checked = false;
    this.state = {
        fields : {
          id: listwebsites.id
        }
    }

    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
    this.selectOnlyThis = this.selectOnlyThis.bind(this);

  }
  click(value){
    this.props.handleChangess(this.state, value);
  };

  render() {
        const {listwebsites} = this.props;
          return (
            <tr>
              <td><input id={`checkbox_${listwebsites.id}`} value={listwebsites.checked} onChange={e => this.click(e.target.checked)} type="checkbox" name="record"/></td>
              <td>{listwebsites.name}</td>
              <td>{listwebsites.url}</td>
            </tr>
          )
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't get your question. Do you want that you checkboxes works as radio buttons, where only one at time can be selected?

Comment: yes i want my checkbox work look like the radio button

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the `Tablerow` component should be stateless (i.e. *controlled*) and the parent component should hold an array of selected rows as its state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you do it, in TableRow's parent which is App.js in this snippet, use `selectedId` state which store the id or TableRow's listwebsite's id if checked and will be null if not checked.

Inside your TableRow render, use `disabled` attr in your`<input/>` element. The `disabled` will check the `selectedId` props passed down from `<App/>`, if `selectedId` not null and `selectedId` value !== current `<TableRow/>` listwebsite's id, then disable the `<input/>`.

```js
const listwebsitesData = [
  { id: 1, name: 'name-1', url: 'Url-1' },
  { id: 2, name: 'name-2', url: 'Url-2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'name-3', url: 'Url-3' }
]

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedId: null,
    }
    this.handleChangess = this.handleChangess.bind(this);
  }

  handleChangess(id, value) { 
    this.setState({selectedId: value===true?id:null})
  }

  render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {
        listwebsitesData.map((data)=>{
          return <Tablerow selectedId={this.state.selectedId} listwebsites={data} handleChangess={this.handleChangess} />
        })
      }    
    </div>
  )
  }
}

class Tablerow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    let { listwebsites } = this.props;
    listwebsites.checked = false;
    this.state = {
      fields: {
        id: listwebsites.id
      }
    }

    this.click = this.click.bind(this);
    this.selectOnlyThis = this.selectOnlyThis.bind(this);

  }
  click(value) {
    this.props.handleChangess(this.state.fields.id, value);
  };

  selectOnlyThis(){

  }

  render() {
    const { listwebsites, selectedId } = this.props;
    return (
      <tr>
        <td><input disabled={selectedId && selectedId!==listwebsites.id} id={`checkbox_${listwebsites.id}`} value={listwebsites.checked} onChange={e => this.click(e.target.checked)} type="checkbox" name="record" /></td>
        <td>{listwebsites.name}</td>
        <td>{listwebsites.url}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, move the selection state one level up. You must be looping over Table row, in a Table component one level up. Put a state field there, say, 'selectedId', and pass it as prop to all the Table row components. Later, onChange will propagate from Table row with 'id' to Table onChangeHandler, for 'selectedId' update. In the render function for Table row, simply add say `checked = id === selectedId` thus, making only one of the Table rows selected at any given time. To make it more generic, you can later add say 'multiple' true/ false flag, where the component can switch between allowing multiple vs single checkbox selection.

Working example
https://codesandbox.io/s/zn9l7qpn83

By default, first one would be selected. As you select another one, it would deselect the other one; thus allowing only one to be selected at any given time.

Hope it helps!

Comment: tanks for helping, can you edit my code with your answer?!

Answer (score 0):

You should add **"checked={}"** on checkbox and return true for the time you want it checked.

```
<input checked={selectedId && selectedId!==listwebsites.id} id={`checkbox_${listwebsites.id}`} value={listwebsites.checked} onChange={e => this.click(e.target.checked)} type="checkbox" name="record" />
```

This will check your checkbox when only this condition **(selectedId && selectedId!==listwebsites.id)**